# Installing package imutils in PyCharm

Tags: python, package, imutils

I need the package imutils in my PyCharm project. However, I can't seem to find this package in pycharm available packages. How can I install this? I am using python 3.6 and anaconda as a project interpreter.

Thanks for any response!

Comment: did you check if the project view and if the package is listed there?

Answer (score 0):

When you go into the package manager, there is an Anaconda icon in the form of a green circle on the right-hand side.  This specifies whether or not to use the Conda Manager for packages.  Click on the circle to de-select this option and you should be able to search for imutils in the new list.

I have attached a screenshot of the Pycharm Package Manager:

[image: PyCharm Package Manager Screenshot]